# JAXB - Using namespace prefixes defined in XSD

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm wondering if there's a way to enforce JAXB to create the same namespace prefixes as the XSD schema. i.e. even though I create JAXB classes from a schema which has xmlns:cts="http://cts.com" in it, after marshalling the class, I get an XML with a xmlns:ns1 prefix. I'm aware that I can override these by using a NamespacePrefixMapper class, but why do I need to do this manually when my XSD clearly defines the default prefixes? I have a ton of prefixes in my current XML, so manual changing of package-level declarations or class annotations are also a huge rework after initial xjc generation. I'm dealing with a base XSD with 10+ XSD imports and 5000+ elements, along with tens of root elements.

Endpoint system is out of our control, so I do have to care about what prefix gets used in the XML as they don't have a proper XML processing implementation.

Is there any shortcut for this? Thanks for all the input.

Regards,
Gökhan

Answer (score 2):

The simplest shortcut is for the producer and consumer of XML to use standard XML processing tools. You say that doesn't work in your situation.

The upshot is that in order to keep your data consumer from incurring the effort of learning to use existing off-the-shelf XML tools, you are going to incur the effort of having to produce not just correct XML but correct XML that meets additional arbitrary ad hoc constraints at a level of abstraction most XML software is designed to conceal.  That may be worth it if they are very good customers.

Concretely, I'd either (1) find a way to automate the configuration changes you want to make to the JaxB-generated classes, or (2) write a simple SAX filter to normalize namespace prefixes, and run the data through that filter on its way out the door.   The second approach has the virtue of moving your data consumer's concerns to the periphery of your own processing and letting you focus better on things you care about more.